# Dispatching ComputeShaders from background threads in unity

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, gpu, compute-shader

I have a Unity project that runs a background thread which makes use of a compute shader to process an image.
I can't Dispatch() this shader from the background thread since Unity only supports them on the main thread. So I am storing it in some queue and handling it in the next Update() call of the component.
However, this means that the background thread has to wait for the next frame to come around for this to be picked up.
If my target frame rate is low (say 15hz) this could be too long and I need this shader to run **now**.

What is the proper way to do this? Is there a way to dispatch these from the background thread directly? Is there a way to somehow force the main thread to do it right now?

I thought "Graphics Jobs" was intended for just this purpose but it either doesn't work or I am enabling it wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to dispatch or use compute shaders and compute buffers from background shaders. The problem is they are something like unity componets, that can't be edited from not main thread.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).